# How can I get all classes within a namespace in android?

Tags: java, android, class, namespaces

How can I get all classes within a namespace in android?
I found some links for java but they do not work for android.

**Edit:**

I want to iterate on classes which I defined in a package. these classes have a static field that I want to get its value. I get that field using reflection but I can not loop on my defined classes.

How can I loop on my classes?

Thanks,

Comment: What namespace do you refer to? I somehow cannot interpret this term in the context of Android development. What classes exactly are you trying to fetch?

Comment: My own namespace not android namespaces.

Comment: java has packages, c# and c++ have namespaces.

Comment: I think you are looking for [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for Reflection.  Reflection allows you to inspect yourself programmatically and determine characteristics, like whether you implement an interface or a method by a particular name.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Comment: I din not find anything about namespace in these links. It is only about classes.

Comment: If you want to scan packages, you can try this:  http://code.google.com/p/reflections/ but I didn't review it enough to know if it would fit your needs.  see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection