# Finding classes at JVM Runtime

Tags: java, classloader

Is there anyway to find all the class names which are extending a particular class by using classloader information?

#### More Detailed Explanation

I have a jar file which has 3 classes `X` (`extends A`), `Y` (`extends A`) and `Z` (`extends B`). I have put this jar file into the classpath and start the JVM (calling main method of some class). Now from this main method is there any way to find the classes which are sub classes of `A`?  i.e. classes `X` and `Y` as they are extending the class `A`.

Comment: I think this should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class

Comment: What feature are you trying to offer the end user by doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to do it. The JVM has no information about a particular class until it gets loaded by a classloader. But to have the classloader actually load the class, you must know the name of the class. Chicken and egg problem.

However, there is some other, but a bit more complicated way.

1. To determine which `.jar` files are on the classpath when running your application, you can call the `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` then split the classpath entries along the `File.separatorChar` characters. Classpath entries may be numerous, consider filtering them somehow (limiting only to a specific directory, leaving out standard entries like `rt.jar`, etc.)
2. If you know which `.jar` file contains your classes of interest, you can open it with an instance of the class `JarFile`. Then you can iterate over all entries (eg. `.class` files) and from their internal path in the JAR file you are able to construct their fully qualified class name.
3. With the classname in your hand, you can call `Class.forName()` to load the class, and the you can use reflection to get the superclasses of each class to find out whether it extends your particular class or not.

Note that this method is quite resource consuming, you make the JVM to actually load all the classes from a `.jar` file (or multiple `.jar` files), even if you won't use them later. This wastes a fair amount af memory (PermGen space).

There are some low-level libraries that manipulate Java bytecode and class files (see [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)). Using them you will be able to determine the superclass for a class without actually (class)loading it, thus this way is more faster and uses less memory.

Your question resembles the way JavaEE application servers work when deploying a web application. To find out which classes to load and initialize as for example HTTP servlets they must examine all classes in the web archive looking for a specific Java annotation or superclass. However they are at least know which `.war` file to scan. Apache Tomcat for example uses BCEL instead of Java classloading mechanism.

If you're designing some sort of dynamic classloading mechanism for your application, then consider other design options to narrow down the numbers of classes your loader must scan to find the proper class to load: Telling the exact name of the `.jar` file instead of putting it on the classpath, using some meta information in the JAR (you can use the aforementioned `JarFile` to read entries from the `META-INF/manifest.mf` file) to specify which classes to look for, etc.

Answer (score 0):

just fore the sake of completeness
http://code.google.com/p/reflections/

others where mentioned in the linked post