# java list all the child classes of a parent

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At runtime, find all classes in a Java application that extend a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class)

I need to get list of all the classes (child) which extends a particular class (parent) and then create an instance of them all.

how should I do this in Java?

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class

Comment: I assume that there are some constraints, for example a set of packages. It is impossible to find every classes that extend a certain class without any constraint given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use http://code.google.com/p/reflections/

> Using Reflections you can query your metadata such as:
>
> - get all subtypes of some type
> - get all types/methods/fields annotated with some annotation, w/o annotation parameters matching
> - get all resources matching matching a regular expression

This can be used in an indexed or cached mode.  As @Jagger suggests, a brute force search of every class is relatively slow. You can also limit the search by package e.g. `com.mycom.*`

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to use the reflections API for finding all the classes which extend a given class. I might be wrong though. I.e. You can easily use the reflections API to get the supertypes of some type, but not to get all possible subtypes of a type.

Comment: This is what the library does. Not to be confused with [The Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) which as you say doesn't do this. ;)

Comment: My mistake. Disregard my previous comment. I focused mainly on reading the grey box and assumed you meant java.lang.reflect.