# Using reflection to get a list of all classes that extend a "Solid" class

Tags: java, reflection

I know how to using Reflection determine the super class of a class.  So if I had a game, and I had a map editor, and I wanted it to have a panel with a button to select select any type of Solid that can be added to the game and add it, I could theoretically use reflection to look through all the classes in my game and see which ones have the super class "Solid", and then add a button to the panel. The only thing that prevents me from doing this is that I need a list of all classes to search through, is there a way I can get that?

Comment: The idea is that you can write plugins that extend `Solid` and add them to the program?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class).

Comment: @chrylis You know when you use the code "Main.class", and it returns a Class<Type>?  I want a Class<Type>[] that contains all classes I defined in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the Java [Service Provider Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). It gets around this problem by having you list the implementing "plug-in" (provider) classes in the jar manifest. You then use `ServiceLoader` to ask for all of the available implementations, and you only have to use `Class.forName`. [Here's another useful overview.](http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/3848881/Service-Provider-Interface-Creating-Extensible-Java-Applications.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into this.  If I get it to work, I'll mark as answer.  Some quick example code would be really nice, and I'd give a 1up.

Comment: Just look at the docs on `ServiceLoader`. For all of the classes implementing your interface, you'll just want `ServiceLoader.load(MyInterface.class).iterator()`.