# Create objects of all classes extending an abstract class in java

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class called "ExerciseMovement" in java implementing Runnable and have concrete classes extending the abstract class implementing the run() method. In my client code, I'm trying to create a code that creates objects of all the classes that extend the abstract class and start their threads. I'm not sure if I can do that without actually knowing what classes extend the abstract class. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class) can help you?

Comment: That's [easy](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/). Although I would recommend you use a thread pool rather than raw `Thread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Java has a mecanism for that. What you could do is "register" each implementing class on a ExerciseMovementRegister which could give you a list of the classes. This would need to be done in a static block (which is not ideal). Creating objects for them is then trivial (pseudo-code, not compiled!):

```
List<Class<? extends ExerciseMovement>> exerciseClasses = ExerciseMovementRegister.getClasses();

for(Class klass: exerciseClasses) {
  ExerciseMovement move = (ExerciseMovement) klass.newInstance();
  move.start();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be a `List<Class<? extends ExerciseMovement>>`?

Comment: You also have a rawtype at `for(Class`.

Answer (score 1):

**Knowing all subclasses is not directly possible in java.**

There are two ad-hoc solutions to this problem.

1. Scanning entire classpath:
   For this purpose, you can use [**Reflections library**](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/).

   ```
   Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package.prefix");

   Set<Class<? extends ExerciseMovement>> subclasses = reflections
                     .getSubTypesOf(my.package.prefix.ExerciseMovement.class);
   ```

   You'd get what you want in 2 lines.
   Now creating objects and starting threads is easy.
2. Have each class register itself (in static block) to the base class (`ExerciseMovement`) and maintain a list of all subclasses.

   Although it is easy to do, it won't work for all subclasses. Only **subclasses** which have **already** been **loaded by classloader** will be available to you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can't get all classes which extend a superclass with standard reflection. But you can solve this in an object oriented way:

```
public abstract class ExerciseMovement 
{
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static ArrayList<Class> inheritedClasses = new ArrayList<Class>();

public ExerciseMovement()
{
    inheritedClasses.add(this.getClass());
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public Object[] createInheritedObjects()
{
    ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();

    if(inheritedClasses.size() > 1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < inheritedClasses.size(); i++)
        {
            Class c = inheritedClasses.get(i);
            try 
            {
                result.add(c.newInstance());
            } 
            catch (InstantiationException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return result.toArray();
}
```

}

This is definitely not a good solution, but it's the only one possible with native java

Comment: The fact that you're having to `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` shows you that you're doing something you shouldn't be. **Never** use rawtypes.

Comment: You could use instead ? extends ExerciseMovement