# Create class list from maven dependency jars during maven build

Tags: java, maven-3

I want to read classes within dependency jars getting downloaded during maven build(dynamically) and write them in a file inside resources folder. Is there a way to do it? I am new to maven and I tried all possibilities to do this but couldn't find a way. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the maven-dependency-plugin and generating a dependency tree with an outputFile. I don't have a running example, but you can take a look of the plugin documentation here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html
On the usage section you have configuration approaches that may be useful to achieve what you need.
You can also generate the dependency tree in a separate maven run with this command:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Doutput=/path/to/file
```

as is told in the usage section of the plugin documentation.

Hope this helps

Comment: This won't allow me to read the jar as stream isnt't it ? Because my aim is to read the classes within that jar file.

Comment: You can take a look to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class this solution may be valid to write a test who writes loaded classes by classloader to a file. You can also execute main class  with -verbose:class  which gives you a list of loaded classes. Hopes this be useful to achieve your needs.