# Refactor dependecy injection of 32 classes that extend the same abstract class with Dagger

Tags: java, abstract-class, vert.x, dagger

I'm working on a project with Vert.x that uses Dagger for DI, and there's a class that's creating an unsustainable problem with how big the injection is done.

### This is the class that I have:

```java
public class ClassManager {
    private List<ParentClass> all = new ArrayList<>();

    @Inject
    public ClassManager(ParentClass... classes) {
        if (classes != null) {
            all.addAll(Arrays.asList(classes));
        }
    }
    //other methods down here
}
```

The problem being that, as of right now, we have 32 classes that extend from this abstract class `ParentClass`, so the injection right now is as this:

```java
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public ClassManager provideClassManager(SubClassA a, SubClassB b, SubClassC c.... and so on) {
         return new ClassManager(a, b, c...and so on);
    }
```

I haven't found so far a better solution on how to do this injection with Dagger, but I do need that this `ClassManager` has access to all of the classes that extend from `ParentClass`. Is there any other better way? Maybe with other library?

Comment: Have you tried using the dagger verticle factory approach? It's described [here](https://medium.com/@michel.werren/dependency-injection-in-vert-x-with-dagger-2-7087bc6b9f4f)

Comment: or just something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/205573/592355)/[that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/347248/592355)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dagger multibindings and bind your subclasses into set, like this

```java
@Module
public abstract class SubClassModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoSet
    public abstract ParentClass bindsSubClassA(impl: SubClassA);

    @Binds
    @IntoSet
    public abstract ParentClass bindsSubClassB(impl: SubClassB)
}
```

And in module with class manager pass set into constructor

```java
@Provides
@Singleton
public ClassManager provideClassManager(Set<ParentClass> set) {
    return new ClassManager(set);
}
```