# Create Object from each Java file in a directory

Tags: java

Is it possible to loop through all Java files in a given directory and create a Java Object from each of those files? Assume all files are Classes.

Example:
Assume I have a directory named "playing_cards", and each file in this directory correlates with one of the 52 playing cards and they all inherit the same Class: PlayingCard.

```
List<PlayingCard> deck;
for(File file: playing_cards){
  deck.add(new PlayingCard(file.path()));
}
```

Comment: First qurestion: Why?  Second question: Does this solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-a-java-application-that-extend-a-base-class

Comment: Yes, but it's going to be a very advanced solution involving reflection. Is there a reason all 52 playing cards are of separate class types? It would make far more sense to have one `PlayingCard` class which takes constructor arguments (from enums, perhaps)